# Wrong discount calculation on WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to give an extra 2 % discount when the user selects a specific payment gateway, & the 2% discount will be applied on the base price of the (exclusive tax).

for example, a price of a product is 2599 inclusive of 18% Tax, and its base price should be 2202.54 (exclusive tax) the 2% discount should be 44.0508 but it's giving me 42.62
This is the product link you can see the issue here [Product URL](https://snd.in/product/staranddaisy-multifunctional-intelligent-early-education-baby-walker-grey/)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'snd_extra_discount_on_ccavenue', 999, 1 );
function snd_extra_discount_on_ccavenue( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // Set the payment gateway ID to check against
    $target_payment_gateway_id = 'ccavenue';

    // Get the current payment gateway ID
    $chosen_payment_gateway = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

    // Check if the chosen payment gateway matches the target payment gateway ID
    if ( $chosen_payment_gateway === $target_payment_gateway_id ) {
        // Calculate the discount amount (2% of base price)
        $discount_percent = 2;
        $discount = 0;

        foreach ( $cart->get_cart_contents() as $cart_item ) {
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
            $base_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_price', true );
            $subtotal_excl_tax = $cart_item['line_subtotal'] - $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax'];
            $discount += round( ( $subtotal_excl_tax / $base_price ) * $base_price * ( $discount_percent / 100 ), 2 );
        }

        // Add the discount as a fee
        $cart->add_fee( __( 'CC-Avenue Discount', 'woocommerce' ), -$discount, false, 'standard' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function snd_extra_discount_on_payment_gateway( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // Set the payment gateway IDs to check against
    $target_payment_gateway_ids = array( 'ccavenue', 'razorpay' ); // add more gateway IDs as needed

    // Get the current payment gateway ID
    $chosen_payment_gateway = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

    // Check if the chosen payment gateway matches any of the target payment gateway IDs
    if ( in_array( $chosen_payment_gateway, $target_payment_gateway_ids ) ) {
        // Calculate the discount amount (2% of subtotal)
        $discount_percent = 2;
        $discount = 0;

        $subtotal_excl_tax = $cart->subtotal_ex_tax;

        $discount = ($subtotal_excl_tax / (1 + WC()->cart->tax_total / $subtotal_excl_tax)) * ($discount_percent / 100);

        // Add the discount as a negative fee
        $cart->add_fee( __( 'Prepaid 2%  discount', 'woocommerce' ), -$discount, false );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'snd_extra_discount_on_payment_gateway', 999, 1 );
```

Comment: This answer needs an explanation of what the OP did wrong (order of operations)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).